# Rails test controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Trying to test my controller

**static_pages_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

    RSpec.describe StatigPagesController, type: :controller do
      it 'return home view' do
        get '/'
        expect(response).to render_template :home
      end

      it 'return about view' do
        get :about
        expect(response).to render_template :about
      end
    end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
end
```

and i get errors

```
   1) StatigPagesController return home view
        Failure/Error: get '/'

         ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
           No route matches {:action=>"/", :controller=>"statig_pages"}

  2) StatigPagesController return about view
     Failure/Error: get :about

     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"about", :controller=>"statig_pages"}
```

**I wrote routes, What i'm do wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your `static_pages_controller_spec.rb`

```
RSpec.describe StatigPagesController
```

Try:

```
RSpec.describe StaticPagesController
```